# Subtract next row use current row, python dataframe

Tags: python, datetime, numpy, pandas, dataframe

I have this Pandas Dataframe in python, I want to know the time difference between two rows, next row subtract previous row, how should I approach this?

Reviewed[x] - Reviewed[x-1] x is the number of where that row is

```
   ReporterID        ID      Type                   Reviewed
0     27545252  51884791  ReportID 2015-01-14 00:00:42.640000
1     29044639  51884792  ReportID 2015-01-14 00:00:02.767000
2     29044639  51884793  ReportID 2015-01-14 00:00:28.173000
3     29044639  51884794  ReportID 2015-01-14 00:00:46.300000
4     27545252  51884796  ReportID 2015-01-14 00:01:54.293000
5     29044639  51884797  ReportID 2015-01-14 00:01:17.400000
6     29044639  51884798  ReportID 2015-01-14 00:01:57.600000
```

Comment: df.Reviewed.diff() could work. 
Source: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.diff.html

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Assuming your `Reviewed` column are datetimes you can do:

```
df.ix[4, 'Reviewed'] - df.ix[3, 'Reviewed']
```

If you want to do it for all rows at once:

```
df['Reviewed'] - df['Reviewed'].shift()
```

Comment: are you suggesting a loop? x is length of the row count? Reviewed is datetime

Comment: do you want to do it only for the row with index `x` or for all rows?